# How can i get the distinct column count and split the one column into two and its count by using where condition in hive?

Tags: hive

For example : Here I want to get the distinct values from col1, based on the col1 distinct values, I want to get total count for col2 and I need to get the count for col3 by splitting the values into two columns as predicted and actual.

[image]

The output should be like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, 
       count(*)                                            as col2, 
       sum(case when col3='predicted' then 1 else 0 end)   as predicted,
       sum(case when col3='Actual' then 1 else 0 end)      as actual
 from your_table
 group by col1;
```